# Only parent class columns created cassandra using cassandra-spark connector

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I have one base class:

```
abstract class Student(id: String) extends Serializable
```

and child class :

```
case class StdAdd(id: String, name: String, class: String) extends Student(id)
```

Persist Code :

```
val newStd: Student = new StdAdd("S001", "Xyz", 4)
sc.parallelize(Seq(newStd)).saveAsCassandraTable("demo", "newStd")
```

But when I check table in Cassandra only one column in stored

```
cqlsh:diwo> SELECT * FROM details;

+------+
|  id  |
+------+
| S001 |
+------+
```

Used following sbt dependencies :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "1.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.4.0"
```

Comment: The initialization of your example has cast `newStd` as your abstract class. Can you try replacing it with `val newStd = StdAdd("S001","Xyz", "4")` and running it again?

Comment: What if I have two sub classes? Do I need to persist them separately.

Comment: Added an answer containing hopefully some relevant information to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

Your unexpected output is the result of casting `newStd` as your abstract class instead of the case class. If you try with the following line instead, you should see the expected output from the query:

```
val newStd = StdAdd("S001","Xyz", 4)
```

With respect to your other question, you don't *need* to persist them separately but it really depends on what your subclasses are doing. If, for example, you have a sub-class that is a simple data type conversion of another, then Cassandra will apply this conversion automatically:

```
case class StdAddConvert(id: String, name: String, class: Long) extends Student(id)
val newStdConvert = StdAddConvert("S001", "Xyz", 4L)
sc.parallelize(Seq(newStdConvert)).saveToCassandra("demo", "newStd")
```

If you are trying to create a case class that is a subset of another one, you could use the previous case class with `None` in place of the non-existent parameter instead:

```
val noClassStd = StdAddConvert("S003", "Xyz", None)
sc.parallelize(Seq(noClassStd)).saveToCassandra("demo", "newStd")
```

If you have another case class that has contains essentially the same information as the initial one, but is defined differently, you can apply aliasing (and data type conversion) to save into the table:

```
case class DifferentStudent(identification: String, tag: String, grade: Int) extends Student(identification)
val diffStd = DifferentStudent("S003", "tag1", 12)
sc.parallelize(Seq(diffStd)).saveToCassandra("demo", "newStd", columns = SomeColumns(
  "id" as "identification", "name" as "tag", "class" as "grade"
))
```

When you have other case classes that contain more student information but extend `Student` to keep `id` as the key (say, `case class StdInfo(id: String, address: String, dob: Long) extends Student(id)`), it doesn't really make sense to have all of that information in one table. Instead you can create persist two tables and apply a join whenever you want both sets of information in the same context.